# electron-packager failing to build when run as root

Tags: electron

**The problem**

I run these commands:

```
git clone electron-quick-start
cd electron-quick-start
npm install
npm install electron-packager --save-dev
npm run-script pack
```

which runs:

```
electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune
```

When in vagrant, as user vagrant, it works.

When I run it in vagrant, as root, it fails with ENAMETOOLONG error.

When I run in Docker container, as root, it fails the same way as well.
Problem is my CI, buildbot, runs as root.

vagrant path: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/node-v6.4.0-linux-x64/bin`

root path: `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/node-v6.4.0-linux-x64/bin`

I've tried using `--out=dist --ignore=dist` but that doesn't work.

I've [read](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/issues/207) that if you specify what to package it might fix this, but I don't know how to do that.

**Successful run as user vagrant**

```
$npm run-script pack
> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 pack /home/vagrant/electron-quick-start
> electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune
Packaging app for platform linux x64 using electron v1.3.4
Wrote new app to /home/vagrant/electron-quick-start/MyApp-linux-x64
$
```

**Error run as user root**

```
$npm run-script pack
> electron-quick-start@1.0.0 pack /root/electron-quick-start
> electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune
Packaging app for platform linux x64 using electron v1.3.4
[ { Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, unlink "/root/electron-quick-
start/electron-packager/linux-x64/MyApp-linux-x64/resources/app/
electron-packager/linux-x64/MyApp-linux-x64/resources...
(Alot of repetition)...
MyApp-linux-x64/blink_image_resources_200_percent.pak"

at Error (native)
errno: -36,
code: "ENAMETOOLONG",
syscall: "unlink",

Several screens full of similar error, but different file names at end, finally:

npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/node-v6.4.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "run-script" "pack"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! electron-quick-start@1.0.0 pack: "electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune"
npm ERR! Exit status 1
$
```

**Environment Info**

```
Mac OS X 10.11.5
Vagrant version: 1.8.4
Linux CentOS 7 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
node version: v6.4.0
npm version: v3.10.6
electron version: 1.3.4
electron-packager version: 7.7.0
Python version: 2.7.5
Buildbot version: 0.8.14
Buildslave version: 0.8.14
Twisted version: 16.3.2
```

Comment: did you tried to build using a script?? see here in the api of electron-packager [link](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: I've just tried running as script, same results.

Comment: Haven't found fix for this problem, but worked around it by provisioning my VM with sudo only when NEEDED, not for `pip install` ' s etc.So Buildbot worker running as vagrant now and all is well.

Comment: More detailed explanation of how I worked around it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190540/how-can-i-run-buildbot-build-steps-on-worker-slave-as-non-root/39193689#39193689)