# How can I run Buildbot build steps on worker/slave as non-root

Tags: python-2.7, buildbot

I'm having issue building electron via electron-packager when I run it as root. However, it works just fine when I run it as other user, say, vagrant.

I've already asked question regarding the problem [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186791/electron-packager-failing-to-build-when-run-as-root?noredirect=1#comment65715634_39186791)

However, I think that if I can configure Buildbot to run as non-root on worker/slave I can get past the issue.

I just can't find any resources that explain such a configuration setup.

I'm running Buildbot Master and Worker(Slave) an separate Vagrant CentOS7 VM's. All is working, but build step that calls `npm run-script build-linux` fails as described in linked question.

**Environment info**

```
Mac OS X 10.11.5
Vagrant version: 1.8.4
Linux CentOS 7 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
Python version: 2.7.5
Buildbot version: 0.8.14
Buildslave version: 0.8.14
Twisted version: 16.3.2
```

Comment: If you want a worker to run as non-root. Then that's trivial, just log into a non-root account and start the worker. Is it that you want to run only *one step* as non-root? (FWIW, I'd do it the other way around. Run everything with normal privileges and then have a step that depends on root access run with elevated privileges.)

Comment: @Louis You are so right! I'll post as answer with details of what I did. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buildbot-slave was running as root because I was using sudo in the provisioning script, i.e.

`sudo pip install buildbot-slave`

Fix was simply using:

`pip install buildbot-slave`

Running `twistd --nodaemon --no_save -y buildbot.tac &` via supervisord.
Set user=vagrant in buildbot.conf file. Need to `vagrant ssh` into vm to run `supervisord -n &`, as running that via provision.sh during vagrant up still runs buildslave as root.

Thanks to comment by @Louis for pointing me in right direction.